# Saving a dictionary with a Pickle and how to read it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I am having trouble trying to save a dictionary using pickle in python:
my code is the following:

```
import re
import os

def save_obj(outputFolder,obj, name ):
    directory = outputFolder + ' obj/'
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    with open(directory + name + '.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(obj, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

The Error message is the following:

```
File "CleanPEPS.py", line 14, in save_obj
pickle.dump(obj, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
NameError: name 'pickle' is not defined
```

It is a problem of library or something like that? Or there is something that I have forgotten?

Comment: You probably havent set-up/ imported the library right

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `import pickle`. Other than that your code looks OK. If you have any more issues check out the [pickle docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Comment: Its saving but it is putting a `txt.pkl` with it why? If its forced to save as `pkl`?

Comment: Because that is the file name you're specifying... `with open(directory + name + '.pkl', 'wb') as f:`. The file name can be whatever you want.